# Appending multiple lines to CSV with for loop in python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, append

I have written code to create a multiple line CSV file. For this purpose one column will write default values and the other columns will have blank values to be edited later.

What results from the code is the headers being created correctly, but all list values being merged into the first row.

```
import csv

# Write Headers
headerlist = (['Class', 'Grade', 'Semester'])
with open('venv/User Data/Classes.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    dx = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',',
                        fieldnames=headerlist)
    dx.writeheader()

# Define Default values
Default = [
    ['Math', 'English', 'Science', 'History']
]

# Write Default values to Class column
for name in Default:
    with open('venv/User Data/Classes.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        a = name
        b = " "
        c = " "
        result = {"Class": a, "Grade": b, "Semester": c}
        result_object = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=headerlist)
        result_object.writerow(result)
```

Was expecting 4 lines to be created with values under the class column and blank values in the other two.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using

```
result_object.writerow(result)
```

The writerow() function writes one row. To write multiple rows, I suggest that you try the following:

```
result_object.writerows(result.values())
```

The difference is the use of the writerows() -notice the S at the end- function which will write multiple rows.
Note: You may end up needing to turn the list of values in your result dictionary into a list in order for the writerows() function to accept it.

Comment: But they are calling `writerow` inside a loop, shouldn't that also write multiple rows?

Comment: Thank you. I believed the for loop would iterate over the writerow multiple times, but I see what you mean. Based on your advice I solved it by creating the list of items with a for loop and writing the rows all at once with that list.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates the list of values in a variable with the for loop then writes them all at once.

```
import csv

# Write Headers
headerlist = (['Class', 'Grade', 'Semester'])
with open('venv/User Data/Classes.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    dx = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',',
                        fieldnames=headerlist)
    dx.writeheader()

# Define Default values
Default = [
     'Math',
     'English',
     'Science',
     'History'
]
#Create empty list
result = []
b = " "
c = " "
# Create list of rows
for name in Default:
    compile = {'Class': name, 'Grade': b, 'Semester': c}
    result.append(compile)
    print(result)

with open('venv/User Data/Classes.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=headerlist)
        writer.writerows(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).